# What happens exactly when we right click a URL and choose "Save as" in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, download

What actions does the IE take when we right click the following URL and choose "Save as"?

```
http://www.somesite.com/some_file.zip
```

I heard of something like "HTTP Download", what exactly is it?

My understanding is, HTTP is a text based protocol, how could it be used to transfer different kinds of files?

My guess is, when we choose Save as for a URL, IE (or any other browser) will open a new TCP connection to the server and do the file transfer. It should have nothing to do with HTTP.

- When we visit a web page, browser use TCP connection to transfer HTTP
  info and HTMLs.
- When we download file in IE, browser use TCP to transfer file content.

**It's essentially the same, only differnt in what's being transfered.**

Am I right?
   connection to tranfer file content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transfer any binary data over HTTP. For example the server could set the `Content-Type` response header to anything and then write any data to the response. So for example you could set the `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` and then write binary data to the response. So what IE does is that it analyzes the Content-Type response header, downloads the contents and if it is a known content type that it can display (such as HTML for example) it displays it inline, if not, it prompts the user to save it.

HTTP is not a text based protocol. The headers should be text but the body of the request/response could be arbitrary bytes. That's what the headers are used for: to indicate exactly how is the body encoded so that the other party could understand and decode it appropriately.

As far as TCP and HTTP are concerned, HTTP is a protocol on the top of TCP. So when using HTTP you are implicitly using TCP. Think of it as a convention based protocol over the main transmition mechanism which is TCP. TCP is low level: it is what allows the connection between the client and the server. HTTP is like a language. Without HTTP, TCP is like two people from different countries, each speaking a different language, meeting in a bar. What do you think will happen? They won't be able to exchange a word. HTTP is the common language that unites them and allows them to talk. TCP is just the bar.

Comment: Vivid and impressive! Thanks for your answer. I think the browser should be able to identify the meaning/format of the bytes it received in the response body. Because as I tried, I used **Response.WriteFile("test.png") to create a response**, and I didn't specify any Reponse Headers, IE was still able to recognize the png format and display the picture correctly. It doesn't prompt me to download the png file.

Comment: IE is a special beast. If there's no Content-Type response header it uses heuristics to guess the type by looking at the first few bytes and trying to match some well known type. For example all image formats could be recognized by looking at the header. It is bad practice to rely on that though because other browsers might not show it correctly.

Comment: So when a HTTP response arrives at the browser, the response looks like **a few HTTP headers in ASCII format and followed by arbitray bytes**. And IE will guess with clues like content-type header, or just try to find the magic number of some file format in the arbitrary bytes. Could you point me to some reference related to how HTTP protocol really works with various browsers? Maybe this is an excessive request. I will really apprecaite it if there's any.

Comment: I would recommend you reading the HTTP protocol specification: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt This is how it should work. As far as the specifics of various browsers is concerned, this is something that I am afraid no single document covers.

Comment: Thanks for your further answer.